# Are there members in people's ancestry who claim to have seen Jesus, or witnessed His acts?

Tags: witness

Historians/writers were able to get written accounts of Jesus's life and acts from the eyewitness accounts of people who had seen Him during His lifetime. It occurred to me that I have not seen or heard claims from people in this lifetime (or a few previous) stating that their ancestors met or saw Him, whether based on story passed down or diary/journal documentation.

I know there's got to be an obvious reason, but I'm stumped on why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some families amongst the Ancient Churches of the Levant (Syria, Lebanon etc.) that do claim descent from particular apostles. For example, some members of the [Semaan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaan#Semaans_of_Antioch_and_Syria) family claim descent from the Apostle Peter. Similarly for the families Andraos (Andrew), Hanna (John) and Matta (Matthew).